# Pentaho - Couldn't find SQLSERVER drivers to connect

Tags: sql-server, exception, jdbc, driver, pentaho

I've recently been trying to use this tool called Pentaho for making SQL reports, but it seems that the tool doesn't find the correct classes/libraries. I have searched all over but mostly people use it to connect through MYSQL instead of SQL SERVER, so there's no resource on the web that helps connect the database.

I have followed the instructions to put the mysql driver into the jdbc folder but it's no use.

The problem I get is     **ParentException: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load the driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver**

And the log:

```
org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.ReportDataFactoryException: Failed at query: SELECT * FROM Client;
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:254)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SQLReportDataFactory.java:95)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcPreviewWorker.run(JdbcPreviewWorker.java:103)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
ParentException: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load the driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.DriverConnectionProvider.createConnection(DriverConnectionProvider.java:106)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.getConnection(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:184)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SimpleSQLReportDataFactory.java:239)
at org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.datafactory.sql.SQLReportDataFactory.queryData(SQLReportDataFactory.java:95)
at org.pentaho.reporting.ui.datasources.jdbc.ui.JdbcPreviewWorker.run(JdbcPreviewWorker.java:103)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is there anybody that had the same problem and might have a solution?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of PDI are you running and what driver do you want to use? 'MS SQL Server' or 'MS SQL Server (native)'? Also, are you using Pentaho Kettle, or Pentaho reporting?

Comment: You haven't included the driver in the classpath, or configured Pentaho where to find it. The steps to configure for MySQL or SQL Server are basically the same, the details differ (driver jar, driver filename and things like the JDBC url)

Comment: I'm using the Pentaho Reporting for MS SQL Server(Native).
@mark-rotteveel I think that is the main problem, the only thing I did following the tutorial was extracting the driver and putting in the libraries directory. I couldn't find a file that I need to specify the path for the drivers